# Javascript combining array list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to combine an array of strings together into a one lined variable

So for example I want the end result to render out like:

`"tag[]=sku_helloworld&tag[]=sku_bridesdark&tag[]=stuk_home"`

This is what I have at the moment and I'm unsure on how to combine it alltogether?

```
var productSku = $('.social-module').data('magento-sku'),
  str = productSku,
  skuList = str.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < skuList.length; i++) {
  console.log("tag[]=" + skuList[i] + "&");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tvdberf7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it a little bit like this:

```
var productSku = $('.social-module').data('magento-sku'),
  str = productSku,
  skuList = 'tag[]=' + str.split(',').join('&tag[]=');
```

See the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0hktaeqb/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var skuList = ['sku_helloworld', 'sku_bridesdark', 'stuk_home'],
    result = skuList.map(function (a) {
        return 'tag[]=' + a;
    }).join('&');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

ES6

```js
var skuList = ['sku_helloworld', 'sku_bridesdark', 'stuk_home'],
    result = skuList.map(a => 'tag[]=' + a).join('&');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in one string, then print it.

```
var productSku = $('.social-module').data('magento-sku'),
  str = productSku,
  skuList = str.split(',');
  var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < skuList.length; i++) {
  result += "tag[]=" + skuList[i] + "&";
  console.log(result);
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvdberf7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use reduce (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
skuList.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + "&tag[]=" + b }, "").substring(1)
```

The `substring` takes care of removing the first `&`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to handle this, however you would need to explicitly add on your first delimiter :

```
// Array.join will build a string using your delimiter '&tag[]=' between
// each of the items in the array
var result = 'tag[]=' + skuList.join('&tag[]=');
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/zanile/edit?js,output).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the list like this:

```
skuList = str.split(',').map(function(item) {return "tag[]=" + item}).join('&');
console.log(skuList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner with no looping:

```
'tag[]=' + productSku.split(',').join('&tag[]=')
```

```js
var productSku = $('.social-module').data('magento-sku');

alert('tag[]=' + productSku.split(',').join('&tag[]='));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-magento-sku="sku_helloworld,sku_bridesdark,stuk_home" class="social-module"></div>
```